# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in file handling in c

Tags: c

i am new to stack overflow so please forgive me if have disobeyed any rules. I am trying to run a code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int o[100][100];
int a[100][100];
int b[5];
int H,W;
int alpha;
int min()
{
    int i,m=b[0],k=0;
    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
       if(b[i]<m)
       {
           m=b[i];
           k=i;
        }
     }
     return k;
 }
 int set(int j,int k)
 {
     b[0]=a[j][k];
     b[1]=((j-1)>=0)?a[j-1][k]:12000;
     b[2]=((k-1)>=0)?a[j][k-1]:12000;
     b[3]=((k+1)<W)?a[j][k+1]:12000;
     b[4]=((j+1)<H)?a[j+1][k]:12000;
     int dir=min();
     int j1,k1;
     if(dir==1)
     {
          j1=j-1;
          k1=k;
     }
     else if(dir==2)
     {
          j1=j;
          k1=k-1;
      }
      else if(dir==3)
      {
         j1=j;
         k1=k+1;
      }
      else if(dir==4)
      {
         j1=j+1;
         k1=k;
      }
      if(o[j1][k1]==-1 && dir!=0)
          set(j1,k1);
      if(dir==0)
      {
          o[j][k]=alpha;
          alpha++;
       }
      else
      {
          o[j][k]=o[j1][k1];
       }
}
int main()
{
    printf("2");
    FILE* f1=fopen("B-small-practice(1).in","r");
    FILE* f2=fopen("otput.out","w");
    if(f1==NULL)
        printf("error in f1\n");
    if(f2==NULL)
        printf("error in f2\n");
    int i,j,k;
    int T,dir;
    fscanf(f1,"%d",&T);
    for(i=1;i<=T;i++)
    {
        alpha=97;
        fscanf(f1,"%d %d",&H,&W);
        for(j=0;j<H;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<W;k++)
            {
                fscanf(f1,"%d",&dir);
                a[j][k]=dir;
                o[j][k]=-1;
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<H;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<W;k++)
            {
                if(o[j][k]==-1)
                {
                    set(j,k);
                 }
             }
         }
         fprintf(f2,"Case #%d:\n",i);
         for(j=0;j<H;j++)
         {
            for(k=0;k<W;k++)
            {
                fprintf(f2,"%c ",o[j][k]);
            }
            fprintf(f2,"\n");
          }
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
}
```

when i ran this code without file operation then it ran successfully but when i used file then it gave segmentation fault. i had this problem many times. please help me in identifying problem in my code so that i can never repeat that mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to find the problem?

Comment: Why do you keep messing up the code format after we fix it for you?

Comment: it says error in function set at line 27(b[4]=(((j+1)<H)?a[j+1][k]:12000;))

Comment: sorry sir. i am new to stack over flow.

Comment: Regardless of what you might have been led to believe, Stackoverflow is not a debugging service. Posting a code dump and saying 'it crashes' does not constitute a good or useful question, especially since waaaay too many such questions get asked every day. Also, the community has no tolerance for new users who don't bother to read the rules before asking. Read [ask].

Comment: yes sir i will agree with you. but no one is there to help me sir. many web sites are asking money which i cant afford to but i want to become a good programmer sir, so i am just asking a help

Comment: show contents of `B-small-practice(1).in`.

Comment: actually file is very large. i am trying a problem of code jam qualification round 2009,B question. There you can find the input file

Comment: @AdlaSutej If you want to become a good programmer, asking for help is the last thing you should do. You should keep trying to solve your problem *by yourself* for as long as it takes. That includes searching the Internet and trying to understand error messages. And like I said, this question does not meet this site's standards and will hopefully be closed soon.

Comment: Why are you fprintffing ints with "%c "?

Comment: We don't know what your code is supposed to do.  The single-letter var names and array-indexing would take up too much contributor time to bother untangling.  Sorry, but your question and code suc... coud do with improvement.  Get out your debugger and find out what index is out-of-range in your problem line of code.

Comment: @MartinJames actually i am storing ascii values of lower case alphabets in matrix o.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault is the program trying to access memory it is not allowed to.

You say that the error is on the line `b[4]=((j+1)<H)?a[j+1][k]:12000;` so I would assume that either `j+1` or `k` exceeds the bounds of the `a` array.

I will not debug this for you, since you say taht you want to learn to become a good programmer, and part of becoming that is debugging.

Start by inserting printouts of variables, e.g. in the beginning of the `set` function. In addition, you should always check that the input that you from the file is within the legal range.

As a general programming tip; Try to work on the readability of the code. Readability is usually more important than making clever code. The compiler will most of the times optimize your code, and is usually more clever than the programmer. Trying to be clever can sometimes give the opposite effect, where the compiler does not recognize a pattern and does not optimize for you.

Comment: thank you sir. but i have a question here i am checking whether j and k are exceeding or not. here  H and W are the range of matrix a. i will debug the code again by inserting print outs of variable in set function as you said . another thing sir it was working completely without file operation . that means when it is reading from stdin then it was working properly but when i used file then it showed me segmentation fault. Thank you sir for your help